# A class loaded at runtime cannot find a class inside a JAR file which is inside a folder Lib

Tags: java, reflection, jar, classpath

Its tricky to explain.
I have a JAR file framework.jar which loads a class `sikuli.class` from a folder Libraries and executes a function `xyz()` 
Now this `sikuli.class` file uses some other JAR files which are API

I have added these APIs while creating the framework.jar and bundled them inside it.

but when I am executing the JAR file it says `ClassNotFound` for all the import statements inside the `sikuli.class` file

I tried adding the API JAR files to CLASSPATH also, even that didn't work.

> Edit

it is the
`Class cls= Class.forName(sClassName,true,classes);`

which is failing to load classes after creating a JAR file 
the same code works when I run it through eclipse

Comment: sikuli.class is loaded by using Reflections,

Comment: ClassNotFoundException is a checked exception, which is thrown when your application tries to load the class using it's name, but no appropriate definition is found. the forName method of Class class, or loadClass method of ClassLoader class may throw this exception. Do the following checks :
1. Confirm that the name of the required class is correct.
2. Ensure your jar files are present in the classpath. I think, that is the problem.
3. If your jar is present in the classpath, then there is a possibility that your classpath is getting overriden, or your app is using classpath specified in jar.

Comment: I thiink my classpath is getting overriden. what should i do ?in this case

Comment: I will suggest you to use a build tool like Maven. Look into this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883226/how-to-prevent-third-party-jars-on-the-classpath-from-overriding-my-class-depend

Comment: ok thanks i'll look at this.!

Comment: @de_xtr i would like to know one more thing the jar files are present inside my Framework.jar so why is it not working?

Comment: the jars have to be co-located, not nested. You cannot do that without writing your own classloader, which will extract from the jar in runtime and put it in classpath. That's why people use Shade plugin or create one single big jar. I will suggest you to go through this link and the related chapters. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html