# Maven subdependency conflict at runtime with Twilio

Tags: java, maven, cassandra, twilio, thrift

Getting a class not found error at runtime due to maven sub dependency issue:

I am working on integrating twilio sdk ( com.twilio.sdk:twilio:7.35.0 ) into a multi module maven(3.x)/java(java8) project.
I firstly added the twilio maven dependency to the corresponding module
And I am getting a class not found exception at runtime on org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager.
I looked into it and found out that this class is part of org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient (which is a subdependency in the twilio sdk ) and that an earlier version of this dependency is in my project. 
And this earlier version does not have the HttpClientConnectionManager class.

So from this point, I tried to exclude the old version of the dependency with exclude tag first then with maven enforcer plugin and in the same time importing the dependency directly but nothing worked.
I tried to import the dependency in the parent pom and in the other modules that are using my twilio module as well.

I am using twilio 7.35 which uses org.apache.httpcomponents:4.5.6 but in my multi-module project I am using org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-thrift:3.0.0 which is using thrift:0.9.2 which contains the old version of httpclient(4.2.5).
The latest version of this cassandra module does not support the latest version of httpClient, so I need to make sure this httpclient older dependency does not mess up the twilio one.

I also analysed the output of mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose and it seems that the 4.5.6 is getting picked up correclty. And when I tried adding it to the parent module or the calling module, I can see that the old version is getting overwritten by the twilio one but it does not solve my issue.

I am starting to wonder if it is even possible to have two versions of the dependencies in the same maven project.

Comment: Please provide a minimum viable example.  Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more details!

Comment: In Maven, you can only have one version of a dependency in the dependency tree at the same time. There are ugly work-arounds with the maven shade plugin, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are experiencing something similar to a related question dealing with Jar Hell: [Jar hell: how to use a classloader to replace one jar library version with another at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909306/jar-hell-how-to-use-a-classloader-to-replace-one-jar-library-version-with-anoth)

In this case you need to use a separate classloader from the default one in your project. Perhaps you could use the [URL Classloader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) and load some or all of your newer dependencies from the filesystem.