# How to set priority of using class

Tags: java, spring

I am creating web service. I have application tier and web tier. Both of this tier using jaxb to generate object factory from xsd. Generating class are in package: my.package.v1

Now I have another project which has dependency on these project.
In context I have specify object factory:

```
<bean id="objectFactory" class="my.package.v1.ObjectFactory" />
```

when I compile and deploy application everything is OK. But there is two Object factory and he can use just one of them. Which one application use and how I change it and use another one ?

UPDATE:

Is there options how to set in spring context which class to use ?
I want change this to set right class when I have two ObjectFactory

```
<bean id="objectFactory" class="my.package.v1.ObjectFactory" />
```

Comment: *Why* would you generate the same names in the same package? It's just asking for trouble. Separate out the packages.

Comment: I dont know :). I am just junior programmer and this was idea of seniors

Comment: I suggest you raise it with them then. It really is a bad idea to have the same fully-qualified name mean two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be conflicting results and depends on Contextual classloader. I would suggest to have them in separate packages to avoid namespace conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Which one of the two implementations of my.package.v1.ObjectFactory that is actually used depends on the ClassLoader.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105124/java-classpath-classloading-multiple-versions-of-the-same-jar-project) question for info on how ClassLoaders resolve this kind of issue.