# What is the name of the jar that contains my import?

Tags: java, eclipse

I do not think this is a duplicate.  I cannot find the simple answer I am looking for.

In Eclipse (Juno), I want to highlight any single import statement and find out which jar contains that package/class.

Is this possible in Eclipse? If so, how?

**EDIT**

This question looks very similar, but does not answer my question [How to know the jar files being used in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400352/how-to-know-the-jar-files-being-used-in-eclipse)

**EDIT 2**

Thank you for the answers, my problem is solved.  I want to point out, however, for the edification of others, that the `ctrl + shift + t` solution provided by Adarshr only displayed the name of the jar when the highlighted `import` statement did **NOT** include the semicolon (`;`) at the end of the statement.

I was highlighting the entire package name, class name, and semicolon, and it did not display the jar name.

Comment: I don't think this is currently available.  If it is, it's new.  The place I used to work for had to write a home-grown plugin to do what you are describing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is already possible. Just highlight the class and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

[image: Eclipse]

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had a lengthy comment to this solution, which I have included in the question as Edit 2, FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the import and 'open' it (f3)... it will open the location it is sourced from, whether it is a jar or some source file.

It will (if you have your editor linked to the package navigator) also hilight the locaton in the left package tree...