# What jar file an import uses?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've downloaded an example code that has some imports, e.g:

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
```

I have the relevant jars in my build-path, and no warning appears. But how do I know from which jars  exactly I import the above? (I want to know this so I can add javadocs to those jars).

I use Eclipse IDE

Comment: have a look at mvn repository  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.net.httpserver/http/20070405

Comment: [FindJar](http://www.findjar.com) can be helpful at times.

Comment: What is the IDE?  Most IDEs will have way to take you the class by just double clicking. That also shows which jar it came from

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733027/what-is-the-name-of-the-jar-that-contains-my-import

Comment: In general `com.sun` classes are internal to the JDK. And one should avoid using them. It certainly might not be available in other JREs, like from the OpenJDK on Linux or MacOSX. Here it is a borrowed interface probably for http server design.

Comment: Take a look here, you can do it with Java.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983839/determine-which-jar-file-a-class-is-from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse IDE or IBM RAD, WSAD etc, Press **Ctrl+Shift+T** in eclipse window. Now type the name of the class file. It will show the contained jar.

For eg: HttpExchange is present in rt.jar

[image]

Comment: I don't see the jar, just the packages, e.g: com.sun.net.httpserver - [jdk1.7.0_60]

Comment: @fatsokol That "jdk"  line means it's part of the standard JVM libraries (as does the com.sun namespace, whose classes you should almost never use explicitly, since they're not an official part of the platform).

Comment: @fatsokol Have added a screenshot. Open the class file in eclipse. Enable "Link with editor" button. So here you can see AWTUtilities is present in rt.jar. Similarly you can find others as well.

Answer (score 0):

in linux you can use shell-script to view inside all jar files. something like this may help you:

```
for i in $(ls *.jar)
do
  unzip -l $i | sed -r "s/^[ 0-9:\-]+/$i /" | grep ".class" | tr '/' '.'
done
```

the output is a pair of (jar-name, class-fullname) for example:

```
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.util.NewsCollection.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.util.NoColumnCollection.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.util.NoHeaderCollection.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.util.PanelInterface.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.util.ParentFinder.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.util.SelectionHelper.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.util.TabsInterface.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.util.TabsUtil.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.util.TagUtils.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.util.TreeviewInterface.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.util.WidgetUtils.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.workflow.LayoutPlugin.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.workflow.LayoutRequestProcessor.class
Struts-Layout-1.2.jar fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.WriteTag.class
```

you can search your class in this output to find jar-file name.