# OJDBC6 to OJDBC7 driver update cause ClassCastException

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc

We updated OJDBC driver in our application from OJDBC6 to OJDBC7. And got strange ClassCastException. Inside logs shows that at:
 `oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource$ThreadedCachingBlockSource$BlockReleaserListener.(BlockSource.java:348)` 
we got:
 `java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.management.MemoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.management.NotificationEmitter`

And we have no idea why this exception is appeared, because according the http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/management/MemoryImpl.html MemoryImpl implements NotificationEmitter.

If we change JVM from Hotspot to the IBM (both JDK7), we got the same:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.lang.management.MemoryMXBeanImpl incompatible with javax.management.NotificationEmitter`

And again MemoryMXBeanImpl implements NotificationEmitter.

So if anybody have the workaround or any idea why does it happens I'll be very grateful!

Comment: Does `javax/management/NotificationEmitter.class` appear in two different sealed jars or could there be two versions of it loaded in different class loaders?

Comment: from logs I get:[Loaded javax.management.NotificationEmitter from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\rt.jar] and [Loaded javax.management.NotificationEmitter from file:/C:/development/newSRC/lib/j2ee/jars/j2ee.jar] so it seems I have to instances of the same interface, if there any way to say JVM not to use one of them?

Comment: I think ["Multiple Versions of the same ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105124/java-classpath-classloading-multiple-versions-of-the-same-jar-project) describes your problem.  ["Handling multiple versions of the same class"](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-classloader-handling) explains some solutions.  One solution not mentioned is to force a parent classloader to load the class first, so the two different classloaders will not load it, but instead use the parent's.

Comment: Thank you Mike, after we make some order in the jars that we used, (actually, now starting to use j2ee.jar version without the javax.management package), everything starting works fine!!!

Comment: Good to hear.  Happy classloading.