# How to merge two jar files with same name but with different version in a project?

Tags: jar, maven-jar-plugin, jarjar

I'm using two jar files like `httpclient-4.2.3.jar` and `httpcore-4.2.jar` but now I want to use another two files with same name but different version `httpclient-4.3.4.jar` and `httpcore-4.3.jar`. How can I use all four files in a same project?

Please help me.

Comment: can you update your code to use the newer version?
mixing various versions is a bad idea.

Comment: actually at some places we require old version same thing i am trying to update but it is not happening so we need to merge it

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105124/java-classpath-classloading-multiple-versions-of-the-same-jar-project

Comment: i need your help. i am using grails 2.3.7

Comment: I don't do grails, sorry.

Comment: but u can help me using maven

Comment: or jarjar tools how can i use it

Comment: in principle you could unpack your jars, merge the files an package them into combined jar again. but this is not going to work: java files contain code with non-trivial dependencies so you are going to break the functionality (there is a reason why they are packaged separately), moreover this will not satisfy maven dependencies (it will still depend and ask for those versions and it will not know about your merged version).

Comment: then please guide me in proper way