# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/spec/alpha__init.class or clojure/spec/alpha.clj on classpath

Tags: clojure

I was trying to understand Clojure spec. While setting up a clojure project I am getting following error while requiring the clojure.spec.alpha:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/spec/alpha__init.class or clojure/spec/alpha.clj on classpath., compiling:
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
at clojure.main$script_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:335)
at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:330)
at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

My project.clj:

```
(defproject testing "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
                 [org.clojure/spec.alpha "0.1.143"]
                 [org.clojure/core.specs.alpha "0.1.10"]])
```

and core.clj:

```
(ns testing.core
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]))

(defn foo
  "I don't do a whole lot."
  [x]
  (println x "Hello, World!"))
```

I will be thankful, if someone can help me out.

Comment: The same project.clj and core.clj are working for me. I notice `com.intellij` in the stack trace; how are you running this? Are you able to run `lein repl` in the project directory from the command line?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `lein repl` command?

Comment: `lein repl` runs ok for me too. Could you please describe how exactly did you run it?

Comment: Here is when i try to run  lein repl:
`lein repl
nREPL server started on port 61605 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:61605
REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.12
Clojure 1.9.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_151-b12
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e`

Comment: I just tried to run core.clj

Comment: Are you using Cursive or some other Intellij plugin?

Comment: Yes, im using Cursive

Comment: Same error with no project, just java -jar clojure-1.9.0.jar (on Windows 10)

Comment: You might try removing `org.clojure/spec.alpha` and `org.clojure/core.specs.alpha` (`spec` ships with Clojure 1.9) and re-booting `Cursive`.

Answer (score 4):

I did a `lein clean` and it started working

Comment: please provide some details if there are.

Answer (score 3):

For those who experience this problem on 1.9, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/-ovhQXtzhgw/XBm_rfcICgAJ

With 1.8, you can just run `java -jar clojure-1.8.0.jar` that you have in your .m2 and RELP will start instantaneously. With 1.9, it's no longer the case. You need additional libraries that you might not have in your .m2 by default.

You will have them though if you install you Clojure based on [official guide](https://clojure.org/guides/getting_started).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, I don't know clojure but had to fix some `NoClassDefFoundError` exceptions testing Kafka Storm using `org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout`.

First exception was: `NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/IFn`

This I fixed by including [clojure-1.9.0.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/clojure/clojure/1.9.0/clojure-1.9.0.jar) in the classpath.

Next, this exception:

`FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/spec/alpha__init.class or clojure/spec/alpha.clj on classpath`

later realized they have another jar [spec.alpha-0.1.143.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/clojure/spec.alpha/0.1.143/spec.alpha-0.1.143.jar) for this.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: If you add clojure-1.9.0 then will storm not complain about multiple versions of Clojure on class path?

Comment: I didn't see that error. Don't expect it based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34728795/

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was adding `test.check` library as a dependency to my classpath