# Issues with Clojure inter-dependency with different major versions of the same library

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

Disclojure: I am not a `Java` developer and I have little knowledge in `Maven`.

I am facing a problem with `Clojure`/`Lein`. I am developing a project that uses two external libraries/projects that are un-related. Both of the uses the `Sesame RDF` library. One of them is Any23 which uses Sesame `2.x` but the other uses the version `4.x`. The problem is that Any23 won't work with Sesame `4.x` and the other library won't work with Sesame `2.x`.

This means that `:exclusions` one or the other in my `project.clj` file won't work.

Do any solution exists to fix such dependencies issues or am I stuck?

Comment: yikes! I feel for you Neoasimov, that is a crummy thing to have to put up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any easy answers for this problem. Here are some options:

- Upgrade Any23 to use Sesame 4.x
- Use something like [Maven Shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to rename one of the Sesame packages so that they can both be loaded on the same classpath. You may run into trouble if you try to use or share objects between the two libraries.
- Use [Clojure OSGI](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.theoryinpractise/clojure.osgi) to isolate the packages. (This is probably the most difficult option, although also the most 'correct').

For more info, see [Java, Classpath, Classloading => Multiple Versions of the same jar/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105124/java-classpath-classloading-multiple-versions-of-the-same-jar-project) and [Wikipedia's entry on JAR Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell).

Comment: I guess you could also have as an option to split your project in 2 halves that communicate with each other (via REST or a file or stdin/out)

Comment: @TimothyPratley yes I could, in fact it was because I was merging two projects that were communicating using REST that I ended-up with that issue :D

Comment: @daniel-campton thanks! This is what I was fearing. For now, I found the namespace that was causing issue and changed the code not to use it. Since no other code is shared between the two it is now working. I will wait until Sesame get renamed into an Eclipse project in order to have two fully distinct projects :) thanks!