# How to exclude dependencies from leiningen-2.7.1-standalone.jar when creating Leiningen Plugin?

Tags: clojure, clj-http

I'm writing a *Leiningen Plugin* which uses `clj-http` library and it's version `"3.6.1"`.

It turned out also **Leiningen itself** uses `clj-http` library as well but it's version is **old** one which causes me some problems.

Are there any ways to override leiningen's `clj-http` lib version?

Comment: I think your question is somehow similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868991/how-do-i-do-exclusions-for-dependencies-that-are-pulled-in-by-leiningen-when-wri

Comment: @minhtuannguyen yes, I found a workaround that copying the library and changing namespaces and use it that way.