# POI-incompatibility/No such method exception

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-poi

I getting issues when reading excel sheet (xls/xlsx) using poi.I trying reading sheet in two different ways using POIFSFileSystem and XSSFWorkbook.

> When reading sheet getting errors i.e.,incompatibility/No such
>   method.Internally we have used jasper jars (version:5.2) and poi 3.8.I
>   am suspect both jar getting conflicts then i upgrade jasperreport-6.0
>   jar.
>
> while reading excel sheet (apache poi) was referring to
>   weblogic/user_projects/domains/db_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/webdav-app-lib/7dbw8f/APP-INF/lib/
>   poi-2.5.1.jar instead of application/lib/poi-3.8.

But still getting exception.If running without jasperreport jars and able capture excel sheet data.Please help on this.

Comment: Can you post some code.

Comment: and some stacktrace of where exactly the error happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java, Classpath, Classloading => Multiple Versions of the same jar/project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105124/java-classpath-classloading-multiple-versions-of-the-same-jar-project)

Comment: Did you try reading the Apache POI FAQs on [My code uses some new feature, compiles fine but fails when live with a "MethodNotFoundException"](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) and [Can I mix POI jars from different versions?](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N101F8)? (Sounds like you're doing at least one!)