# How to version my Java Services like REST API versioning

Tags: java, api, semantic-versioning, api-versioning

I need a way to version my java service to be versioned like REST. I want to use the  Semantic Versioning and manage my java api lifecycle same as REST. 
Example:-
String runService(String serviceVersion, String inputToService...)

and based on the version it will call to appropriate functionality of the service.

I am thinking of loading separate versions of jar through classloader as descrived in [Java, Classpath, Classloading => Multiple Versions of the same jar/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105124/java-classpath-classloading-multiple-versions-of-the-same-jar-project)

Is there any best possible way to do this or shall I switch to REST.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  It would be inefficient to invoke an interface with an extra version parameter.  Better to just have versioned REST API's.  Let your clients call the correct API's directly.