# How to specify the plugin version in Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium-connect

I have 2 different versions of the same plugin in the worker properties (plugin.path option).

```
GET /connector-plugins
    {
        "class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "type": "source",
        "version": "1.9.6.Final"
    },
    {
        "class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "type": "source",
        "version": "2.5.1.Final"
    },
```

How to use a plugin version in connector.class connector options that are located on the same worker?

```
    "name": "some-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
     ...
```

If I leave this option without a version, the old connector gets an error:

```
    "old-connector": {
        "status": {
            "name": "old-connector",
            "connector": {
                "state": "RUNNING",
                "worker_id": "1.2.3.4:8083"
            },
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "state": "FAILED",
                    "worker_id": "1.2.3.4:8083",
                    "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error configuring an instance of PostgresConnectorTask; check the logs for details\n\tat io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:131)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSourceTask.java:226)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:186)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n"
                }
            ],
            "type": "source"
        }
    },
```

I need to configure the connector for the new version of the plugin so that the connector with the old version of the plugin remains working (both should work) in the one worker.

Comment: It'll use whichever is first on the classpath. There's no way specify a version. I'd recommend deleting the older jars on the worker and restart them

Comment: @OneCricketeer but why? Old connector will work with the new version of the plugin, and there are some compatibility issues with connector configurations. That's why there is a need for connectors of both versions

Comment: The "old connector" is going to use the first available classes that are found on the classpath. That would depend on how the OS scans the files, and you cannot "pick" which version comes first (and therefore used) without renaming the files (and restarting the JVM). This isn't Kafka Connect specific, and that itself doesn't have any option for selecting a version, either.

Comment: As [this answer mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64808347/2308683), every worker needs to have unique set of classnames. Java alone typically starts throwing warnings and unexpected errors when you load two identically named classes that are compiled at different versions

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, I read it. Thanks for answers

As I understand it, the only way to solve my problem is to create a new worker in the cluster?

Comment: To be safer, I'd recommend a new connect cluster, if some workers will have different versions than others.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I'll start with a new [worker](https://forum.confluent.io/t/how-to-create-new-workers-for-kafka-connect-distributed-mode/6930)

Comment: But you also need to remove the older versions from the existing workers. That's why I recommended a new cluster (even if that has one server), not scaling an existing one by adding a worker. It's not recommended to run `connect-distributed.sh` more than once per server

Comment: will there be conflicts even if I specify a new `group.id`, `config.storage.topic`, `offset.storage.topic`, `status.storage.topic` and `plugin.path`?

Comment: That'll create a new Connect Cluster group, like I was suggesting.